# How do i bevel an object with n-gons?

Tags: modeling

So what i have now is this object :
[image]

I applied a simple deform modifier on it which is why there are many edges. Also i deleted all the edges on the front and back faces.

[image]

The problem : When i bevel the edges this pinching occurs. My question is, how do i overcome this and is avoiding n-gons just not possible when i want to bevel the ends to make it curved?

Comment: You can use a bevel modifier with an angle high enough not to bevel the corners or using vertex groups to only bevel the oval loop. Does that work for you?

Comment: the ngon is not the problem here, the problem is your topology density, if you have a too dense topology you won't be able to bevel correctly because it will cause faces overlapping, I'm not sure why your topology is so dense, you should keep it as much low as possible